# Weird pointer-to-something template parameter

Tags: c++, templates

I found this snippet online

```
union U { int a; int b; };
template<int U::*> void f();
         ^^^^^^^^
```

I had never seen `int U::*` as a template parameter, what does it mean?

Answer (score 1):

It's a pointer to `U`'s data member of `int` type.